# Powershell for loop not working. Possible data type or library error

Tags: powershell, for-loop

My code is as follows

```
for($i = 0.25; $i -le 0.70; $i+=0.05)
{
    [array]$taper_ratio += $i
}
```

Should add to the array taper_ratio the values from 0.25 to 0.70 including 0.70 but when I run it doesn't work. Instead what the array contains is

```
PS C:\Users\Austin> $taper_ratio
0.25
0.3
0.35
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
0.6
0.65
```

As you can see no 0.70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `$i.GetType()` in the loop you will see that `$i` is of type `Double`. All floating point types (including double) are actually the closest available value. This means that for example a number is 0.7, but actual value might be 0.69999999999999999999999. In this case it does not satisfy the condition `$i -le 0.70`.

`Decimal` type on the other hand accurately represents the value, so you can convert the type of `$i` to decimal and then the script should work:

```
$taper_ratio =@()
[decimal]$i = 0
for($i = 0.25; $i -le 0.70; $i+=0.05)
{
    $taper_ratio += $i
}
$taper_ratio
```